# post values having single quote lead to issue while using php curl

Tags: php, curl

I have to post values having single quote inside the string to a url using `curl`, single quote automatically stripped I think, how do I properly include single quote in strings while using `curl`,

```
$url = "test.com/req?a=10&b='1010','1012'";  
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$result = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use urlencode.

```
$url = "test.com/req?a=10&b=" . urlencode("'1010','1012'");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i get wrong values in variable b message from my api

Answer (score 0):

This way you can build query string of any complexity:

```
$url   = 'test.com/req';
$query = array(
  'a' => 10,
  'b' => "'1010','1012'"
);

$url .= '?'. http_build_query($query);

// will produce this
// test.com/req?a=10&b=%271010%27%2C%271012%27
```